# Change text color of buttons from black to white and then revert back

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I have ten buttons in a slide out menu. How do I change the text color of the ten buttons from black to white by selection and then revert back to the original state when a user clicks on another button.

I am looping through the buttons one by one and I used the code

```
@IBAction func onBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {

        hmImg.hidden = true
    editprofileImg.hidden = true
    cntctsReqImg.hidden = true
    cntctsManImg.hidden = true
    preferencesImg.hidden = true
    timeRuleImg.hidden = true
    helpImg.hidden = true
    logoutImg.hidden = true


    var a: NSInteger = sender.tag

    if a == 1
    {


        homeBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        hmImg.hidden = false


        }

    else if a == 2
    {
        editProfileBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        editprofileImg.hidden = false

    }
   else if a == 3
    {
        cntctsRequetsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cntctsReqImg.hidden = false

    }

   else if a == 4


    {
        cntctMangBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
         cntctsManImg.hidden = false

    }
 else   if a == 5
    {
        preferenceBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        preferencesImg.hidden = false
               }

  else  if a == 6
    {
        timeruleBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        timeRuleImg.hidden = false

    }

  else  if a == 7
    {
        helpBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        helpImg.hidden = false

    }


  else  if a == 8
    {
        logoutBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        logoutImg.hidden = false

    }
```

the problem with this state is the button color remains white when I select other buttons. I want to change the text color to black when a user selects another button

control state for selection is hardly present for a few seconds when I click on the button

Comment: These all buttons won't work like Radio buttons. On each button click you should revert back other buttons state.

Comment: all my buttons are named differently . should I revert back after every loop . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let buttons = [homeBtn, editProfileBtn, ...]
let images [hmImg, ....]
func selectItemAtIndex(index:Int) {
    buttons.forEach {
      $0.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   }  
   images.forEach {
       $0.hidden = true 
   }  
   buttons[index].setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   images[index].hidden = false   
}
@IBAction func onBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag
    selectItemAtIndex(index - 1) // your tags is 1 based.
}
```

Or you may use a different way which involves less looping.

```
let images [hmImg, ....]
var currentBtn: UIButton!
var currentImg: UIImageView!
@IBAction func onBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
   currentBtn?.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    currentBtn = sender
    let index = sender.tag - 1 // one based tages
    currentImg?.hidden = true
    currentImg = images[index]
    currentImg.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Its worth noting that the less looping is mor efficient.

Comment: @Losiowaty Yes indeed.

Answer (score 0):

you likely want to set the colors for specific states, then change the button state when you need to. Sounds like you want a radio type button set, so have the buttons in an array and when any one button is tapped, change that button's state to "selected" and the others to "normal" or something like that.